# Does Matrazenlager-style accommodation exist outside mountain huts?

Tags: accommodation

In mountain huts in the Alps, it is classically common that all guests share big beds in a [Matratzenlager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matratzenlager):

Does such accommodation exist in any other context, apart from mountain huts?

[image: Matrazenlager]

Matrazenlager at Rifugio Vittorio Emanuele II.  Source: [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Lager_Rifugio_Vittorio_Emanuele_II.JPG), user Svíčková.

Comment: This places requires sleeping bags, so I would assume that if any other place also requires sleeping bags, they have a possibility to offer this kind of beds?

Comment: They require sleeping bags because all people share a mattress, I suppose other places would do the same.  I don't really see how it matters for the question, though.

Comment: I came to think ot [Jjimjilbang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jjimjilbang) - korean bath houses also used for sleeping. Found a [a blog post](http://janetnewenham.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/too-much-nakednesss-not-enough-space/) about it.

Comment: @gerrit so for an answer, you'd be ok with any accommodation (in a hut or otherwise) on which many guests share the same bed/mattress, even if with individual sleeping bags?

Comment: @MarkMayo Correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One example that I've experienced was in Egypt, onboard fellucas, or yachts, while sailing on the Nile.

[image: Night time - sharing the same mattress, with sleeping bags]

[image: Day time, with the curtains still down, for a better view of the mattress]

(both photos are my own).

Comment: Was this accommodation officially sold as such, or just a makeshift improvisation by travellers?

Comment: @gerrit oh no, it's designed like that.  I've had several friends do the same trip, and it's one of the highlights.